# Definite Integral of Fourier Transform

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I came across this problem on this forum in the context of the Fourier Transform, however I was unsure of how to solve it (The answer listed is that given by the user).

Question:
$X(j\omega)=\int_{A}^{B}\sin (\omega_1t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$

Answer:
$X(j\omega)=-\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega)B}}{2(\omega_1-\omega)}-\frac{e^{j(\omega_1+\omega)B}}{2(\omega_1+\omega)}+\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega)A}}{2(\omega_1-\omega)}+\frac{e^{j(\omega_1+\omega)A}}{2(\omega_1+\omega)}$

I am new to these kind of math problems so I would appreciate if someone could explain the math on how to solve such questions as the one mentioned above.

Comment: I think you probably forgot a "t", in your definition ? $X(jw) = \int_A^B \sin{(w_1 t)} e^{-jwt} dt$ should give you the good answer with the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sin \omega_1 t = \frac{e^{j \omega_1 t} - e^{-j \omega_1 t}}{2j}$.  Combine exponentials.  $\displaystyle \int_A^B e^{\alpha j t} \, dt = \frac{1}{\alpha j} (e^{\alpha j B} - e^{\alpha j A}).$

Comment: @mjw Where did the $a$ in the exponent come from?

Comment: What I meant by $\alpha$ is $\mp (\omega_1 \mp \omega)$ depending on the term.  Each term in the integrand is an exponential, and we know how to compute its integral.  I've submitted an "answer" with all the details.  Looks similar to the answer you provided (perhaps a sign or two is flipped, we should double check it!)

Comment: Okay, checked the signs.  It now matches the result you provided.

Comment: Well, not exactly ...  we've got to be careful about the signs in the exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned} 
X(j\omega)&=\int_{A}^{B}\sin (\omega_1t)e^{-j\omega t} \, dt\\
&=\int_{A}^{B}\frac{e^{j\omega_1 t}-e^{-j\omega_1 t }}{2j}e^{-j\omega t} \, dt\\
&=\int_{A}^{B}\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega) t}-e^{-j(\omega_1+\omega) t }}{2j} \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2j} \left[\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega) t}}{j(\omega_1-\omega)} + \frac{e^{-j(\omega_1+\omega) t}}{j(\omega_1+\omega)} \right]_A^B\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega) A}}{(\omega_1-\omega)}-\frac{e^{j(\omega_1-\omega) B}}{(\omega_1-\omega)} - \frac{e^{-j(\omega_1+\omega) B}}{(\omega_1+\omega)} +\frac{e^{-j(\omega_1+\omega) A}}{(\omega_1+\omega)} \right].
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I understand how you have done this, converting the $sin$ function into complex exponents makes sense. However, what if I have a more complicated function such as:

$f(x) =5(1+cos(\omega_1t)) \times sin(\omega_2t)$

Converting the above to complex exponents can get very long and very complicated. Is there any other method I could use?

Comment: Well, in the case we just looked, and in some other cases, integration-by-parts will work too.  To compute $X(jw)$ we would need integration-by-parts twice.  In this example with $\int u \, dv = uv-\int v \, du$ either function ($\sin(\omega_1 t), e^{-j\omega t}$) could have played the role of $u$, and the other $\frac{dv}{dt}$.  You are right.  Writing everything in terms of exponentials and expanding the terms can get tedious, but for these types of examples, it will work.